# Uncaught TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, typehead

I am fetching some records :

```
$companies = \App\User::where('type', 'pet-salon')->orWhere('type', 'veterinarian')->get();
return response()->json($companies);
```

The data coming back is an array of objects:

```
[{
  id: 2, 
  type: "xxx", 
  deactivate: 0, 
  xxx: "Hello", 
  middle_name: "Mid",   
  lastname: "xxx",
  //...
}]
```

This is the jQuery typeahead code:

```
$('#getCompaniesForConnection').typeahead({
  source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get('/all/companies', { query: query }, function (data) {
      return process(data);
    });
  }
});
```

The exception its giving me :

> Uncaught TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function

And the results drop-down is not showing too, What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to json_encode your companies.

```
$companies = \App\User::where('type', 'pet-salon')->orWhere('type', 
'veterinarian')->get();
$result = json_encode($companies ); // return this or echo
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the PHP code looks like it's a laravel code, so you can just return the `$companies` variable like so:

```
$companies = \App\User::where('type', 'pet-salon')->orWhere('type', 'veterinarian')->get();
return $companies;
```

Since models and collections are converted to JSON when cast to a string, you can return Eloquent objects directly from your application's routes or controllers.
And also, let's see the definition of the `process` function to be sure that's not where the error is coming from.